# Is it possible to order columns by values in column name?

Tags: python, pandas

Hey I have Pandas Dataframe:

```
Feature | -1% |  1% | -2% |  2% | -3% |  3% |  - 100% | 100%
feat_A  | 0.21| 22.1| 123 | 21.3| 222 | 171 | 10 | 45
feat_B  | 0.66| 86.1| 183 | 21.3| 999 | 108 |  7 | 78
```

Is it possible to sort columns in ascending order without loosing `%` from name of the column?
Desired output is:

```
Feature | -100% |  -99% | -98% |  ...% | 98%  | 99% | ... 100% |
feat_A  | 0.21  | 22.12 | 123  | 21.3  | 222  | 171 | 
feat_B  | 0.66  | 86.14 | 183  | 21.3  | 999  | 108 |
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `key` parameter in [`DataFrame.sort_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_index.html), added in `pandas 1.1.0` with strip `%` and converting to integers:

```
df = df.sort_index(axis=1, key=lambda x: x.str.strip('%').astype(int))
print (df)
         -100%  -3%  -2%   -1%    1%    2%   3%  100%
Feature                                              
feat_A      45  222  123  0.21  22.1  21.3  171    10
feat_B      78  999  183  0.66  86.1  21.3  108     7
```

For oldier pandas version alternative with [`Index.argsort`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.argsort.html) and [`DataFrame.iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html):

```
df = df.iloc[:, df.columns.str.strip('%').astype(int).argsort()]
```